BigQuery Java API call fails from CloudRun instance after the statup
We migrated one of our services from CloudFuncitons to GCP CloudRun and started getting very weird errors during the first request to BigQuery API.
There are several typical errors:
com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Error writing request body to server
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.translate(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:115)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.create(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:236)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$5.call(BigQueryImpl.java:414)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$5.call(BigQueryImpl.java:399)
at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:103)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryRetryHelper.run(BigQueryRetryHelper.java:86)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryRetryHelper.runWithRetries(BigQueryRetryHelper.java:49)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.create(BigQueryImpl.java:398)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.create(BigQueryImpl.java:363)



com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException: Unexpected end of file from server
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.translate(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:115)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.create(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:236)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$5.call(BigQueryImpl.java:410)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl$5.call(BigQueryImpl.java:399)
at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:103)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryRetryHelper.run(BigQueryRetryHelper.java:86)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryRetryHelper.runWithRetries(BigQueryRetryHelper.java:49)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.create(BigQueryImpl.java:398)
at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.create(BigQueryImpl.java:363)

Errors disappear after several minutes/attempts of calling BigQuery and all work well until the next restart/redeploy of the service.
We introduced Retry mechnanism using external retry library as suggested here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages#connecterrors
But maybe there is another approach to avoid this service "startup" problems?
Do you know what can be the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Hi @ybondar, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
